# Permanent 301 redirect for ASP.NET IIS7

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iis-7, http-status-code-301

Im trying to figure out how to setup a 301 permanent redirect for a website that is placed on a Microsoft-IIS/7.0 type server. 
So let's say I have domain www.A.com  and I want to redirect this to www.B.com I could use something like the following in my web.config file:

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
   <rules>
      <rule name="Redirect to WWW" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="A.com" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.B.com$" />
   </conditions>
   <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.B.com/{R:0}"
        redirectType="Permanent" />
   </rule>
 </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

When placing the web.config in the root directory, the server responds:

> 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
>   You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

Any suggestion why this 403 error is given?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try turning on error tracing to see where the error is coming from. Also, make sure you have the URL Rewrite module installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting a 403 error with a plain (default) web.config and totally vanilla Default.aspx, then there is a configuration problem with IIS.  Most likely the app pool does not have rights to the base folder for the website.  Sounds like you're in a hosted situation so contact the system administrator.

Answer (score 0):

This should work and also be much simpler.  You don't need URL rewriting, just HTTP redirect.

As for the 403, does the IIS application pool have read access to the folder at the root of your site?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="www.B.com" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Well the problem is that I don't have access to a control panel (can only access the site via ftp). Also I only have a basic understanding of how II7 and ASP.NET works so I don't know how to figure out if the IIS application pool has read access to the folder at the root.

Comment: Hm ok well if the site was set up for you, you can probably assume the  proper permissions are there.  You can test by commenting out your existing web.config URL rewriting and put a basic "hello world" default.aspx in the root folder and check if you can request it successfully.  If that all works I would still recommend trying out the config above, it should work fine for you.

Comment: @Kiwi1 OK well based on your question, it seems like HTTP redirect should produce the exact results you want.  So, could you describe how it doesn't work in an edit?

Comment: No luck trying with a basic "hello world" default.aspx. The server still gives me the 403 error. I'm currently using a javascript redirect by using location.replace but I guess that's something I would only use as temporary method regarding search engine indexing etc? The HTTP redirect used in the web.config gave me the same 403 error by the way.

Comment: @wilsonlego For the 403 error, no.  It sounds like Kiwi1 was having a basic configuration problem such as file system permissions but as you can see we did not go into that here.  If you are having a similar problem I recommend you post a new question.